# Solution verification for a probability question

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification

> A dental insurance policy covers three procedures: orthodontics, fillings, and extractions.
> During the life of the policy, the probability that the policyholder needs
>
> orthodontic work is $1/2$;
>
> orthodontic work or a filling is $2/3$;
>
> orthodontic work or an extraction is $3/4$,
>
> a filling and an extraction is $1/8$.
>
> The need for orthodontic work is independent of the need for a filling and is independent
> of the need for an extraction. Calculate the probability that the policyholder
> will need a filling or an extraction during the life of the policy.

**My attempt:**
Let $O, F, E$ denote the events that a policyholder would need orthodontic work, a filling, or an extraction respectively. If $A$ is an event, let $A'$ denote the complement of $A$.

Now, $P(O\cup E) = 1-P(O'\cap E') = 1-\left[P(O')\cdot P(E')\right] = 1-\left[\dfrac{ P(E')}{2}\right] \implies \dfrac{3}{4} = 1-\left[\dfrac{ P(E')}{2}\right] \implies P(E') = \dfrac{1}{2}$

Similarly, $P(O\cup F) = 1-P(O'\cap F') = 1-\left[P(O')\cdot P(F')\right] \implies \dfrac{2}{3} = 1-\left[\dfrac{ P(F')}{2}\right]\implies P(F') = \dfrac{2}{3}$

So, $P(F \cup E) = 1-P(F' \cap E') = 1-\left[\dfrac{2}{3} \cdot \dfrac{1}{2}\right] = \dfrac{2}{3}$, which is, unfortunately, not the correct response. Can someone please review my solution and let me know where I went wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly got $P(F')=2/3$, i.e. $P(F)=1/3$ and $P(E')=1/2$ i.e. $P(E)=1/2$.

Your mistake was then that you assumed the need for filling and the need for extraction were independent. That is *not* mentioned in the problem. Had those events been independent, you would've had $P(F\cap E)=P(F)P(E)=1/6$, but it is not that - it is $1/8$.

Instead, you should've just calculated $P(F\cup E)=P(F)+P(E)-P(F\cap E)=1/2+1/3-1/8=17/24$.